# Proof $Ly = (ky')'$ is self-adjoint

Tags: adjoint-operators

I'm looking for a proof that $Ly = (ky')'$ is self-adjoint. My attempt:

> \begin{align}
> \langle Ly(x), w(x)\rangle &= \int_a^b (k(x)y(x)')'w(x) \,\mathrm{d}x
> \\ &= \int_a^b (k'(x)y(x)' + k(x)y''(x))w(x) \,\mathrm{d}x
> \\ &=\quad\color{red}{??}
> \\ &= \int_a^b y(x)(k'(x)w(x)' + k(x)w''(x)) \,\mathrm{d}x
> \\ &= \langle y(x), Lw(x)\rangle
> \end{align}

Except I'm not sure how to fill in the center part.

Comment: Tried integration by part?

Comment: The operator $L$ probably acts on functions $u$ such that $$u(a)=u(b)=u'(a)=u'(b)=0$$ hence the identity $$\int u'v=-\int uv'$$ used twice, is all you need.

Comment: $\langle Ly,w\rangle-\langle y,Lw\rangle=k(wy'-w'y)|_{a}^{b}$